# Where to change PATH in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, environment-variables, nodejs

What is the correct location to add to my PATH so that it is used across all applications? Currently, my PATH is set in my `.zshrc` file. However, this prevents GVIM from seeing that path, and prevents calls like `:!pdflatex %`.

Do I need to be careful where I put the initialisation for NVM (which executes a shell script rather than setting PATH), if I want to call `npm build` from vim?

I use Kubuntu 20.04 with zsh.

Comment: If system-wide, would be `/etc/profile`. Take a look to [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Answer (score 0):

Since you use zsh I'm not sure, but a common file to make changes to `PATH` is the `~/.profile` file. `~/.profile` is sourced by the DM and a `PATH` change made there ought to be effective in the whole session.

Comment: It's more of a question about Kubuntu than zsh actually. I can source `.profile` in `.zshrc` if I need to.

Comment: @MaxXiong: I doubt that would help. But I suggest that you try `~/.profile`, relogin, and see if it makes a difference.